# deleting from DB using a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi im using a dropdownlist to get id from a table and then delete the line with a delete buton when i run the page teh dropdownlist get all the id's in the table all fine but when i delete it always delete the last id even if i select another

```
List<classe_cv_langues> li6 = new List<classe_cv_langues>();
    SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=p5-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=recrutement_online_3;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd4.Connection = con4;
    con4.Open();
    cmd4.CommandText = "select id from cv_langues as cl inner join cv as c on cl.id_cv = c.id_cv where id_candidat= " + Session["Id_candidat"];
    SqlDataReader dr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr4.Read())
    {
        classe_cv_langues p6 = new classe_cv_langues();
        p6.Id = int.Parse(dr4[0].ToString());
        li6.Add(p6);


    }
    dr4.Close();
    con4.Close();


    DropDownList7.DataSource = li6;
    DropDownList7.DataTextField = "id";
    DropDownList7.DataValueField ="id";

    DropDownList7.DataBind()
```

the delete buton:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=p5-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=recrutement_online_3;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from cv_langues where id='"+DropDownList7.SelectedValue+"'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Server.Transfer("gestion_cv.aspx");
```

Comment: Is your data bind logic executed only if Page.IsPostback = false?

Comment: sorry im a new programmer how i can see this ?

Comment: If you're filling your combo on Page_Load method, be sure that this logic is only executed if Page.IsPostback = false. Adding this as an answer in case it helps

Comment: what is the role of isPostback and why it should be false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your binding logic is on page_load method. Try testing for `Page.IsPostBack`

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    List<classe_cv_langues> li6 = new List<classe_cv_langues>();
    SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=p5-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=recrutement_online_3;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd4.Connection = con4;
    con4.Open();
    cmd4.CommandText = "select id from cv_langues as cl inner join cv as c on cl.id_cv = c.id_cv where id_candidat= " + Session["Id_candidat"];
    SqlDataReader dr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr4.Read())
    {
        classe_cv_langues p6 = new classe_cv_langues();
        p6.Id = int.Parse(dr4[0].ToString());
        li6.Add(p6);


    }
    dr4.Close();
    con4.Close();


    DropDownList7.DataSource = li6;
    DropDownList7.DataTextField = "id";
    DropDownList7.DataValueField ="id";

    DropDownList7.DataBind()
}
```

Comment: ah great that works now and yes im filling my combo in loading page can you explaine what happen now ? sorry im noob :p

Comment: @youssef.abd: testing `IsPostBack` property is used (among other things) to execute initialization logic only on first request and not on post back. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)